# ¿Cual seria la declaracion del interface en la libreria?

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente codigo java

```java
ChangeListener<Number> listener = StrongListener::changed;
```

y luego en su uso

```java
public static void Changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number>prop,Number OldValue,Number newValue){
///codigo de la funcion

}
```

¿Como se definirian ambos de forma generica en la libreria?Vamos,¿cual seria la firma de la funcion al definirla?
Y llegado el caso  ¿proque en la segunda parte que es el uso de la funcion hay que repetir el template

```java
ObservableValue<? extends Number>
```

Supongo que seria

```java
public interface change<T>{

public static <T> void Changed(Observable<? extends  T>,T oldValue,T newValue);

}
```

ejemplo ojo a los lambdas y las static functions

```java
import javafx.beans.IntegerProperty
import javafx.beans.SimpleIntegerProperty
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
 import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

class StrongListener{

public static IntegerProperty counter=new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
public static ChangeListener<Number> listener;
public static void addstronglistener(){
changeListener<Number> listener= StrongListener::changed
counter.addListener(listener);
}
public static void changed(ObservableVaule<? extends Number>prop,Number oldValue,Number newValue){

//printing old and new values

}




}
```

Comment: lo de que sea static lo hace aun mas complicado

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de llamadas secuenciales a tu método de interface?

Comment: no se añadir llamadas secuenciales a mis metodos pues es javafx.beans el que las llama

Comment: Lo que pasa que como lo que pusiste no es una clase no puedo compilarlo, trata siempre de poner un [mcve], así es menos trabajo para quien trate de ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta seria

```java
<E> public void changed(ObservableVakue<? extends E>prop,E oldvalue,E newValue)
```

para  este metodo en concreto

Comment: Trata de entregar una explicación un poco más concisa con respecto a tu respuesta, para que así la comunidad pueda tener un mejor contexto de lo que quisiste hacer :D